# How do I sort an array by a child attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord, nested

I have articles

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 100 }
  validates :text, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 3000 }
end
```

and I have

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  validates :body, presence: true,
                    length: { maximum: 3000 }
end
```

I need to display to the user the list of articles availables, but sorted by the timestamps of the comments. Just like an image board that when you post something on a thread, the thread gets "bumped" to the top.

I managed to come with `<% @articles.joins(:comments).order('comments.created_at desc').each do |article| %>`. It sorts the right way, but it show the same thread times the number of posts on it. For example, if a thread has 5 replies, it is shown 5 different times to the user. How can I fix this?

-edit-
Using group `.group('articles.title')` actually worked. but I discoverd that *joins* does not include articles with no comment yet. I switched it to *includes* and apparently it worked. But now I have the problem that posts without any comments end up in the bottom of the list, and I need them on the top. A solution is to create an empty comment when an article is created, but I dont know how to do that as well -EDIT2- I solved it. I made so that an automatic comment is created together with the post, so every post has a comment with a timestamp to compare. I just put this line `@comment = @article.comments.create(body: '~start~')` on the articles_controller.rb inside @article.save loop

Comment: No need to create empty comments. Most databases can order nulls first or last. Example in postgres would be `@articles.joins(:comments).group('articles.title').order('comments.created_at DESC NULLS FIRST')` [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-order.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group by

```
<% @articles.joins(:comments).order('comments.created_at desc').group('articles.title').each do |article| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `#distinct` on the query: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
# controller
@articles = Article.includes(:comments).order('comments.created_at desc')
```